# Setting CommandTimeout after Execution causes error (column appears multiple times)

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I have a Delphi project which uses the ADO-Components, currently SQL Server 2017.

I noticed that [Microsoft has 3 possible providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) , and Microsoft recommends using "Generation 3" for new projects.

```
  SQLOLEDB (Generation 1) works
  SQLNCLI11 (Generation 2) does NOT work
  MSOLEDBSQL (Generation 3) does NOT work
```

To test the "Generation 3", I changed the provider in the connection string from SQLOLEDB to MSOLEDBSQL.

However, I noticed that this causes a problem if a column is added using a TAdoCommand inside a transaction, and afterwards, the Timeout is set. The error happens when the timeout is set after the execution.

Here is an example that reproduces the problem:

```
uses
  ADODB;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  // SQLOLEDB (Generation 1) works
  // SQLNCLI11 (Generation 2) does NOT work
  // MSOLEDBSQL (Generation 3) does NOT work
  SqlServerProvider= 'MSOLEDBSQL';
var
  mConnection: TADoConnection;
  command: TadoCommand;
begin
  mConnection := TAdoConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    mConnection.ConnectionString := 'Provider='+SqlServerProvider+';Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=CORAMASTER_1;Data Source=SHS\HS2017,49010';

    mConnection.KeepConnection := true;
    mConnection.LoginPrompt := false;

    mConnection.Connected := true;

    mConnection.BeginTrans;

    command := TADOCommand.Create(nil);
    try
      command.Connection := mConnection;
      command.ParamCheck := false;
      command.CommandText := 'alter table TESTTABLE add TESTCOLUMN int;';
      command.CommandTimeout := 100;
      command.Execute;

      // If I set "CommandTimeout" here, I get the following error:
      //        Spaltennamen müssen in jeder Tabelle eindeutig sein. Der Spaltenname "..." wurde in der ...-Tabelle mehrmals angegeben.
      //        Translated: Column names must be unique in each table. The column name "..." appears multiple times.
      // The error happens with provider MSOLEDBSQL (Generation 3) and SQLNCLI11 (Generation 2), but SQLOLEDB (Generation 1) works
      command.CommandTimeout := 50; // ERROR!
    finally
      FreeAndNil(command); // Note: In the real project, I am keeping the command object. This is just for the example
    end;

    mConnection.RollbackTrans;

  finally
    FreeAndNil(mConnection);
  end;

end;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this an error in the ADO components?

**Edit: Here is a trace log of the SQL server using the Microsoft SQL Server Profiler:**

Generation 1 (works):
[image]

Generation 2:
[image]

Generation 3:
[image]

When I perform the second "SetTimeout" command, the SQL server performs the command `exec [sys].sp_describe_first_result_set N'alter table TESTTABLE add TESTCOLUMN int;',NULL,1` which obviously causes the error. I have no idea why `sp_describe_first_result_set` is called and how to prevent it...

Comment: Which Delphi version?  Istr that there was a problem setting ADO timeouts in Delphi a *long* time ago (around D3/D5 era).

Comment: I am using Delphi 2007 (I know it is very old, but unfortunately, I depend on old VCLs/Frameworks that can't be updated)

Comment: Why do you need to set CommandTimeout after command executed?

Comment: I know nothing about that Delphi - but i see a connection created but never opened. Hard to believe that `mConnection.Connected := true;` actually opens the connection. And TRY without CATCH makes no sense.

Comment: @sddk This is just a reproduction example. In the real project I am re-using the AdoCommand object.  Some commands need a lot of time so I temporarily increase the CommandTimeout when I do such special statements. In the end, there is an `procedure ExecSQL(sql: string; timeout: integer)` function which sets the timeout, runs the command, and recovers the previous timeout.
@SMor try-finally-end is usual in Delphi, because it avoids memory leaks in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: @SMor:  Both your comments are incorrect, I'm afraid.  In Delphi, setting the Connected property to True is a perfectly valid way of opening a connection (the actual action takes place in the setter of the property) and it has two `try` constructs, `try ... except` for exception-handling and `try ...finally` for resource protection.

Comment: I have added a picture of the Microsoft SQL Server Profiler:  https://i.imgur.com/wmPpcC0.png   Maybe it helps understanding what is happening.  Looking at the Delphi Source code, it seems like settings the CommandTimeout function directly invokes the Command15.Set_CommandTimeout COM function

Comment: When I perform the second "SetTimeout" command, the SQL server performs the command `exec [sys].sp_describe_first_result_set N'alter table DAUERAUFTRAG add TESTCOLUMN int;',NULL,1` which obviously causes the error. I have no idea why `sp_describe_first_result_set` is called and how to prevent it...

Comment: I have edited my answer below, after I found out something very weird. Can you please look at the edit? I think it is some kind of bug in either Delphi or the provider. I never seen something like this before.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the problem.

Microsoft describes at [Using Connection String Keywords with OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) :

> **Use FMTONLY**
>
> Controls how metadata is retrieved when connecting to SQL Server 2012
> (11.x) and newer. Possible values are true and false. The default
> value is false.
>
> By default, the OLE DB Driver for SQL Server uses
> sp_describe_first_result_set and sp_describe_undeclared_parameters
> stored procedures to retrieve metadata. These stored procedures have
> some limitations (for example, they will fail when operating on
> temporary tables). Setting Use FMTONLY to true instructs the driver to
> use SET FMTONLY for metadata retrieval instead.

If I execute `mConnection.Execute('set fmtonly on')` , then everything works.

In the profiler screenshots (above) I can see, that the Generation-1 driver actually executes these commands very often.

---

**Edit:**
I noticed that `set fmtonly on` does not work for me. For some reason, various things do not work, e.g. all result sets are empty.

But I have found a very interesting thing about the initial problem!
Setting CommandTimeout a second time does ONLY crash if it is called inside the same function call! If I call CommandTimeout immediately afterwards, but inside a new function call, then everything works!

Here is an example:

```
procedure CausesBug;
begin
  command.CommandTimeout := 100;
  command.ParamCheck := false;
  command.CommandText := 'alter table TESTTABLE add TESTCOLUMN'+inttostr(Random(10000))+' int;';
  command.Execute;

  command.CommandTimeout := 100; // Crash!
  // This calls: exec [sys].sp_describe_first_result_set N'alter table TESTTABLE add TESTCOLUMN2729 int;',NULL,1
end;

procedure CausesNoBug;
  procedure Test1;
  begin
    command.CommandTimeout := 100;
    command.ParamCheck := false;
    command.CommandText := 'alter table TESTTABLE add TESTCOLUMN'+inttostr(Random(10000))+' int;';
    command.Execute;
  end;
begin
  Test1;
  Test1; // Although CommandTimeout is the first command, everything works!
         // "sp_describe_first_result_set" is NOT called!
  Test1;
  Test1;
end;
```

And also:

```
procedure AlsoCausesNoBug;
  procedure Test1;
  begin
    command.ParamCheck := false;
    command.CommandText := 'alter table TESTTABLE add TESTCOLUMN'+inttostr(Random(10000))+' int;';
    command.Execute;
  end;
begin
  command.CommandTimeout := 100;
  Test1;
  command.CommandTimeout := 100;
end;
```

Note: I have also tried disabling compiler optimization, to make sure that there are no issues there.